# How can we copy data from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint ONLINE 2013?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

How can we copy/export a library/list that currently lives on SharePoint 2010 and import it to SharePoint 2013 on office 365?

I have searched the web, but I just don't seems to find a good example for this situation.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of third-party tools that can do this for you.  Here are a few:

MetaVis: http://metavistech.com/category/tools-office-365

Express Migrator: http://www.sharepointmigrator.com/sharepoint-to-office-365.html

AvePoint: http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-migration-tools/

Metalogix: http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx

Quest/Dell: http://www.quest.com/migration-suite-for-sharepoint/

Comment: But is there any recommended way of doing it manually ?
or using third party tool is the only option till now.

Comment: You can always write your own migration tool or do it manually, one record at a time...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Save your document library in 2010 as a template.
2. Copy the template file to your desktop.
3. Go to your top-level site collection settings in SP Online and go to "List Templates" from the Designer Galleries section.
4. Upload your 2010 template.
5. Create a new list using that template.

The list you created should have all of the information (with the exception I believe of any workflows). There are limits to how large a doc library swapped out like this can be, and if your library exceeds that size then John Chapman's remedies are the only other way that I am aware of. Nonetheless, I'm almost positive that they left the way that lists and by extension libraries are formatted virtually untouched between these versions and so therefore this should work.

Comment: Lists can also be exported to Excel, and then use that Excel file as template to create a new list (with the data)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a newer, cheaper and much simpler solution.
3 PRO - SharePoint Migrator - https://shop.step2own.com/3-pro-sharepoint-migrator

It migrates from on-premise or filesystem to your SharePoint Online, or vice versa. It maintains users, ownership, dates, and versions.